# Node JS - Add Buffer Values to Create Checksum

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I am working on a piece of code for a node-red application and I am trying to generate a checksum of data.

```
/* Get our global config object */
var conf = global.get("common");

/* Create our payload */
msg.payload = new Buffer([
    conf['head'], // Byte Header
    conf['reserved'], // Reserved Byte
    conf[msg.req.params.zone], // Zone Number
    conf['commonCommand'], // Command
    conf[msg.req.params.action], // Data
    conf['head'] + conf['reserved'] + conf[msg.req.params.zone] + conf['commonCommand'] + conf[msg.req.params.action] // Checksum
]);

/* Return the payload data */
return msg;
```

The last line in the `payload` is the checksum and it is the combination of all the other bytes.

For this example, here are the following bytes:

- conf['head'] = '0x02';
- conf['reserved'] = '0x00';
- conf['zone'] = '0x01';
- conf['command'] = '0x04';
- conf['action'] = '0x20';
- conf['checksum'] = This should be 0x27 (the combination of all previous bytes).

How can I go about adding up the bytes to satisfy the checksum value of `0x27` in this example?

Comment: **Do not use `new Buffer()`** (in general). Instead use [`Buffer.from()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array) in this case.

Comment: @mscdex - Thanks, will change this.

Comment: Also remove the quotes from around the values when you populate `conf` as that will store strings not the hex byte values